# unexpected token error while running PostgreSQL query in Java

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I have created the following query for PostgreSQL which is working fine in SqlWorkbench. But when I integrated this in Java code, I'm getting a syntax error exception:

**Query running fine in SqlWorkbench:**

```
ELECT poaiF.fnsku, 
       poaiF.acknowledgement_type_code AS last_ack_code 
FROM   po_acknowledgement_items poaiF, 
       (SELECT Max(poa.po_acknowledgement_id) AS last_po_ack_id, 
               poai.fnsku 
        FROM   po_acknowledgement_items poai, 
               po_acknowledgements poa 
        WHERE  poa.po_acknowledgement_id = poai.po_acknowledgement_id 
               AND poa.order_id = '5D7P2FLB' 
        GROUP  BY poai.fnsku) t 
WHERE  t.last_po_ack_id = poaiF.po_acknowledgement_id 
       AND t.fnsku = poaiF.fnsku
```

**Query in java (giving syntax error in beginning of (`SELECT Max(poa.po_acknowledgement_id) AS last_po_ack_id`):**

```
private static final String LAST_ACK_CODE_QUERY1 = "SELECT poaiF.fnsku, \n" +
        "       poaiF.acknowledgement_type_code AS last_ack_code \n" +
        "FROM   po_acknowledgement_items poaiF, \n" +
        "       (SELECT Max(poa.po_acknowledgement_id) AS last_po_ack_id, \n" +
        "               poai.fnsku \n" +
        "        FROM   po_acknowledgement_items poai, \n" +
        "               po_acknowledgements poa \n" +
        "        WHERE  poa.po_acknowledgement_id = poai.po_acknowledgement_id \n" +
        "               AND poa.order_id = \'5D7P2FLB\' \n" +
        "        GROUP  BY poai.fnsku) t \n" +
        "WHERE  t.last_po_ack_id = poaiF.po_acknowledgement_id \n" +
        "       AND t.fnsku = poaiF.fnsku";
```

While running the query through the integration test, getting the following error:

> unexpected token: ( near line 4, column 8  which is the beginning of
>   (SELECT Max(poa.po_acknowledgement_id)

I am running through `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean` which is as follows.

```
SessionFactory postgresSessionFactory; //initialized with org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean class.


final Session session = postgresSessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

String query = LAST_ACK_CODE_QUERY;

final Query selectQuery = session.createQuery(query).setTimeout(queryTimeout);
final List<Object[]> terms = selectQuery.list();
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you need the escapes for the `\'`?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 2):

From [Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/7.1.2.Final/org/hibernate/SharedSessionContract.html#createQuery(java.lang.String)) documentation:

> Query createQuery(String queryString)
>   Create a Query instance for the given HQL query string.

If you want a SQL query, you need to use `createSQLQuery` instead:

> SQLQuery createSQLQuery(String queryString)
>   Create a SQLQuery instance for the given SQL query string.

Comment: SQLQuery not working. I could run a simple query with creatQuery. Initial issue was, entity mapping was not right. I corrected it and it ran successfully. But now I am not able to join virtual table. As you see in the original query, I am joining a virtual table, and hibernate is complaining there.